# HtmlAgilityPack does not select subnodes with XPath

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I am trying to find the specific form on the page and all of it's inputs. I've simplified html to this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="http://storeland.ru/user/login" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="act" value="login" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action_to" value="http://storeland.ru/" />
            <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="28450" />
            <input type="hidden" name="to" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="21dc2792" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

but still can't get correct results

```
var htmlweb = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
var doc = htmlweb.Load(...);
var form = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form[@action='http://storeland.ru/user/login']");
var inputs = form[0].SelectNodes(".//input");
```

'doc' represents correct web-page, but SelectNodes returns only

```
<form action="http://storeland.ru/user/login" method="post">
```

without any subnodes, so further selecting returns null in 'inputs'.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is the only form with this action on the page?

Comment: Absolutely! The html quoted in question is exactly what I'm trying to parse now.

Comment: Ok, thanks, just a sanity check: replace `.//input` with `//*` and see what would you get?

Comment: @alecxe, it returns eight nodes (html, body, form, and five inputs)

Comment: @ Andy Korneyev, thanks a lot! `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");` before parsing did help